# Hide PHP variable with CSS

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Can't find an answer to this anywhere, I am sure it's out there but I can see it!

I am trying to hide the suffix variable from showing through CSS (or any other means). I have simply removed it from the code but it's breaking the entire site for some reason.

Code is

```
if (count($redq_product_inventory)) {
    $price_html = '<span class="amount rnb_price_unit_' . $product_id . '"> ' . $prefix . '&nbsp;' . $range . '&nbsp;' . $suffix . '</span>';
    update_post_meta($product_id, '_price', $price);
} else {
    $price_html = sprintf(__('You don\'t have any inventory with this product. This product in not bookable.', 'redq-rental'));
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "it's breaking the entire site". it is breaking the site visually you mean?

Comment: No, WordPress is giving me a debugging error and won't load anything unless in safe mode

Comment: can you show the error?

Comment: It sounds like you introduced a syntax error when you edited that line to remove it. We need to see the error to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the variable from that PHP code shouldn't break the site. Maybe there was just some little error when you removed it. That code line should be:

```
$price_html = '<span class="amount rnb_price_unit_' . $product_id . '"> ' . $prefix . '&nbsp;' . $range . '</span>';
```

(I guess you won't need that last `nbsp;` for the space between `$range` and `$suffix`, so I removed that as well.)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the whole picture... Is it some plugin or default theme functionality? Sure it could break some plugin/theme functionality if you just remove a variable that is used otherwhere. If you need just to not display it here, you can just delete it in this place like this:

```
$price_html = '<span class="amount rnb_price_unit_' . $product_id . '"> ' . $prefix . '&nbsp;' . $range . '</span>';
```

If not, I would recommend first to define what does this variable do and where it is used in the code